# Having trouble with preg_match pinterest username url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Please help the statement i am using for matching pinterest username url is

$url = http://pinterest.com/username

preg_match("|^http(s)?://pinterest.com/(.*)?$|i", $url);

but preg_match result are returning 0

Comment: Add the third parameter to your preg_match function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the third parameter of the `preg_match` function.

```
$url = "http://pinterest.com/username";

preg_match("|^http(s)?://pinterest.com/(.*)?$|i", $url, $match);

print_r($match);
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://pinterest.com/username
    [1] => 
    [2] => username
)
```

Or in an if statement:

$url = "http://pinterest.com/username";

if (preg_match("|^http(s)?://pinterest.com/(.*)?$|i", $url, $match)) {
       // true
   }

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just see if it matches or you want to find the username?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "http://pinterest.com/username";
if(preg_match("|^http(s)?://pinterest.com/(.*)?$|i", $url)){
    echo "true";
}
else{
echo "false";
}

?>
```

**output:**
true

What else you want ?

Answer (score 0):

No one said that need to escape point.
So more correct code will be something like this:

```
$url = "https://pinterest.com/username";

preg_match("|(?:https?://)(?:www\.)?pinterest\.com/(.+)/?|i", $url, $match);
```

It will return username. I don't know the rules that have pinterest for usernames so I just match all that are inside of slashes.

It will work with links like:

1. https://pinterest.com/username/
2. https://www.pinterest.com/username
3. pinterest.com/username
4. and other

**Don't use this regular expression for validation**